# Nested function(Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

a function (funcA) that takes a function (funcB) and returns a function that can be evaluated to produce the same value that funcB would produce (if given the same arguments) plus 1

```
returned_func(x) = funcB(x) + 1
```

What could be the possible way of doing this? I am confused with the second part of the question as to how can a function return a value and function at the same time. Any code example would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Function A doesn't return a function and a value at the same time. It returns a function C, whose result when called is the result of the *expression*; it is supposed to call function B, add 1 to the result, and that sum is the return value of function C.

Comment: any code example would be much appreciated. I am new to Python and learning it on my own. @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept you're looking for is, essentially, a **function decorator**. In Python, functions are first-class objects, just like class instances are in other languages. That means that you can pass them around, just like any other object. For example:

```
def foo(x):
    return x + 1

print(foo)  # <function foo at 0x0000024202F43EA0>

bar = foo

print(bar)  # <function foo at 0x0000024202F43EA0>
```

Here we created a reference to the function object itself. We can, using the same idea, make a function which returns a function:

```
def foo(x):
    def inner(y):
        return x + y

    return inner

func = foo(5)
print(func(3))  # 8
```

`func` is assigned to the return value of `foo`, which is itself a function that we can evaluate. You want to return a function `A` that adds `1` to the result of another function, `B`. So, pass `B` to a function `make_A`:

```
def make_A(b):
    def inner(x):
        return b(x) + 1

    return inner

def B(x):
    return x

A = make_A(B)
print(A(1))  # 2
```

Python has excellent syntactic sugar for this type of function. See [this primer](https://realpython.com/blog/python/primer-on-python-decorators/) for more information.

Comment: wow! thanks for your awesome explanation! I really appreciate it! Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

```
def func1(x):
    #operations go here:
    return(x + 1)

def func2():
    #operations go here:
    return(x - 1)

if func1(2) == func2(4):
    print("Hooray")
```

Does this help? It is a demonstration of how parameters and return values can interact.

A segment like `func(1)` implies the return value with the parameter as 1.

Comment: This isn't quite what the question asker was looking for. They want the result to be a function which returns the result of another function `+ 1`, not just a different function.

Comment: I think the principles I displayed are enough to learn that. It isn't amuch of an extension really.